# Move email off Small Business Server to Google Apps, retain other SBS functions?

Tags: g-suite, windows-sbs

Recently, an in-house Microsoft Small Business Server 2011 was installed where I work. Unfortunately, our buildings have a bad electrical power supply and we suffer frequent outages. We have a large percentage of staff working off-site. Now when the power goes off here, everyone everywhere loses email functionality.

I have been assigned to research the possibility of routing our email to Google Apps while maintaining LAN functions on the SBS. I haven't worked with Microsoft products for several years now, so do not know how SBS is structured.

Can anyone here tell me if this is possible, or point me to good resources that explain our options?

Comment: Does your SBS server as an email server and domain?  Or just an email server?

Comment: It runs both Exchange email and our LAN workgroup domain.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you migrate from Exchange to google apps:

http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/gapps_pilot/intgr_data_email_lotus_mig.html#1100527

Here is the tool you'll need to download:

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/exchangemigration

It should be pretty straight forward on that.  Also, you'll need to update your MX record to reflect google apps and decommission the Exchange part of the SBS.

Comment: Thank you. I had seen reference to the migration toolkit on Google's site. I'll do some searching on decommissioning the Exchange part. That was the key question - I was told that Windows SBS couldn't run without Exchange and that didn't seem right.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't sound correct.  Do you have AD on it?  Does that also act as DC?

Comment: I think Active Directory is active. The description of AD on Wikipedia sounds like the environment we are in.  I think it does also act as domain controller.  My main job is website development, I don't know much about Windows hardware or LANs.

Comment: Then in reality, decommissioning the Exchange shouldn't be that big of a deal once you migrate over to google apps.

Answer (score 1):

Not to push another product, it's just the one I'm familiar with but you may look into Cloud Coexistence with Office 365.  This may give you the performance on-site as well as easy accessibility with offsite users.  Then again, you could just go to Office 365 all together to maintain an Exchange like experience, when we compared it to Google Apps and other providers the integration you get with Outlook and Exchange was much better than the other offerings.

To me it always came down to how invested we already were with Microsoft products versus making a complete switch to another provider.  Our users had grown accustomed to Exchange features which made it really hard to look at Google Apps.  That being said, in either direction you should be able to move a lot of the functions offsite bit by bit to either provider, there's just a good amount of work for whoever gets handed that task.

[Here's some more on coexistence with Office 365](http://blogs.technet.com/b/neiljohn/archive/2011/08/15/office-365-hybrid-deployment-exchange-rich-coexistence-sharing-availability-free-busy.aspx).

Hope it helps,
Brent

Comment: Thank you, it's good to learn of that option. Most of the people in the office use MS products and may find that an easier change to accept.

Comment: @PaulS. If you need help check out MessageOps.com they by far have the best tools and information, plus consulting if needed to help you out with the move.

Answer (score 1):

How long are these outages? get a decent UPS? Might be cheaper over a 3 year period than continuously subscribing to gmails / office 365 prices! (dependent on the amount of users of course)

Comment: Outage time varies. Night before last it was off >4 hours.  Since we are a non-profit organization we qualify to get Google Apps free.

Comment: That is crazy! Get on to your supplier!!